# An "a" element around a "div"

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I know the topic of having an inline element around a block-level element as being semantically invalid has been discussed here at length.

However, the situation of putting an "a" element around a "div" seems unescapable whevener you want to... well... put a link around a box (with CSS-defined width and height for instance). That looks like a very common situation and there's absolutely nothing wrong with the rendering.

But how to do this while staying semantically correct?

Answer (score 6):

I'll note that

```
<a href=""><div>...</div></a>
```

is perfectly valid HTML5.

Comment: This deserves more votes! HTML5 spec allows `<a>` around block level elements!

Comment: Actually it's slightly more complicated than that. The content model of `a` is _transparent_, which means the contents of the `a` can be whatever is valid in the parent of the `a`. In other words, you can have a `div` in an `a` in a `div`, but not a `div` in an `a` in a `span`.

Answer (score -1):

Add a Javascript onclick event handler on the div element

```
<div onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com';" > </div>
```

Or what if you make the div an inline element

```
   <div style="display:inline;"></div>
```

or make the a display as block

```
<a style="display: block;" > </a>
```

Comment: Thanks. OK with the javascript idea, but you drop the anchor in the markup so you alter the meaning.

Comment: I think the downvote is inappropriate here. If the schema says you can't wrap a block-level element with a inline element, you have two options: treat the problem as one of layout and style it; or treat the problem as one of behavior and script it. I think the real question is why the OP feels he has to use a `<div>` when, unlike `<p>` or `<ol>`, `<div>` has no intrinsic meaning. When you need to use a block-element, use `<div>`. When you can't, use `<span>`. Then you style it to get the layout you want and you apply scripting to get the behaviors.

Comment: In fact, using spans rather than divs and display them as block elements may well be the solution (in case the <a> can't be used directly as a block).